# Stopping Capybara + Selenium from opening a browser window during JS tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium, rspec, capybara

I'm using RSpec with Capybara. On tests marked `js: true` it uses the default javascript driver (Selenium).

The test itself passes (see below), but I noticed it opens a Firefox window and then immediately closes it while running the test. As you can see below, the test is pretty straightforward and I don't have anything like `save_and_open_page` anywhere in there.

1. Why do is it do this?
2. Is there a way to disable this? If I have several dozen JS spec tests in the future I don't want a window opening up for each of them.

Thanks!

```
# rails_helper
require "spec_helper"
require "rspec/rails"
require "capybara/rails"
require "capybara/rspec"

# Test
it "user can sign in", js: true do
    visit root_path
    click_tab("sign_up")

    fill_in "session[email]", with: "grace@hopper.edu"
    fill_in "session[password]", with: "gr4ce!"
    click_submit

    expect(current_path).to eq(home_index_path)
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because the Selenium driver uses firefox to execute the javascript in the test. You can use a headless browser such as phantom.js which wont open a browser window. The [poltergiest](https://github.com/teampoltergeist/poltergeist) gem is probably what you are looking for.

Comment: Ah thank you! So I take it there's no option to run selenium in headless mode at all? It absolutely must use Firefox?

Comment: As far as i'm aware it must use firefox. You should be able to swap in phantom.js using that gem fairly easy.